# $M\oplus N$ is free, is $M\oplus 0_N$ free

Tags: homological-algebra

Just a quick question, as the title says let $M,N$ be $R$-modules, if $M\oplus N$ is free, is then $M\oplus 0$ also free? My initial feeling is "no" because it would be isomorphic to $M$ then which need not be free.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking....

Comment: It is because I typoed, i meant for it to be $M\oplus 0$ and not $M\oplus N$ again, my bad!

Comment: What are $M$ and $N$? Are they modules over some ring $R$?

Comment: Correct, I forgot to add that vital information, it has been added, my apologise.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122721/non-free-modules-with-a-free-direct-sum) should help you answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RayX has linked an answer to your question in a comment, but I'll write it down here as well: Over the ring $\Bbb Z_6$, you have the two modules $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$. Their direct sum $\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_3 \cong \Bbb Z_6$ is clearly free, but neither $\Bbb Z_2$ nor $\Bbb Z_3$ are free.

In general, modules $M$ for which there exist a module $N$ such that $M\oplus N$ is free are called *projective*. If there is a *free* module $N$ such that $M\oplus N$ is free, then $M$ is called *stably* free. There are projective modules that are not stably free (the example above is one such), and there are stably free modules that are not free (examples of that are usually a bit more complicated).

Comment: so it was my gut feeling then as it was isomorphic, I pretty much knew this stuff about projective modules but I was wondering and almost hoping there was some hidden thing that could render it free as a submodule, ah well that's life! Thank you though.